# Pattern for instantiating from list of (classes, args, kwargs) tuples

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have a set of (potentially quite complex) Python classes that perform a certain transformation of data, e.g. Principal Component Analysis (PCA). Let's call these **blocks**. **Blocks** are organized in **pipelines** which can have any sequence of blocks. Several **pipelines** are organized in what we call **models**.

I apply these models-with-pipelines-with-blocks in parallel to thousands of datasets. Therefore, I have thousands of instantiations of models (and pipelines, and blocks), since each dataset has its own associated parameters that are stored in the blocks (e.g., the principal components for the PCA).

Now, since I want to have a set of predefined pipelines of blocks, I define some as module attributes in my `pipelines.py`:

```
PIPELINE_A = [(Block1, args_block1, kwargs_block1),
              (Block2, args_block2, kwargs_block2),
              ...
              (BlockN, args_blockN, kwargs_blockN)]
```

The same goes for the models in my `models.py`:

```
MODEL_1 = {'in': (PIPELINE_A, args_pl_A, kwargs_pl_A),
           ...
           'out': (PIPELINE_B, args_pl_B, kwargs_pl_B)}
```

These can be considered pipeline/model configurations from which I can instantiate pipeline and model objects. I don't instantiate them in the module yet, because they should be different for all the datasets.

Because I always need a class name, arguments and keywords arguments, I have to keep these all stored in a tuple until I need them to instantiate the objects (e.g., `[cl(*ar, **kw) for cl, ar, kw in MODEL_1`). This is ugly, and I suspect there is a better way.

I wonder if anyone can recommend a design pattern or trick for this situation.

P.S.
I realize I could instantiate a proto-pipeline/model in my modules and then make copies from that. Blocks can get really complex, though, and I wonder if Python handles deep copying well enough for that.

Comment: How about storing creator lambdas in your `MODEL_1`?  It would look like this:  `MODEL_1 = { 'in': lambda : PIPELINE_A(arg1, arg2, kw1=kwarg1, kw2=kwarg2), 'out': lambda : PIPELINE_B(arg3, arg4, kw3=kwarg3, kw4=kwarg4) }`.  This way you can use normal calling syntax and stlil delay the creation until you need to construct the instances.  (Creation is then done like this: `instance = MODEL_1['in']()`.)

Comment: @Alfe Thanks, that's a great example of the creative tips I'm looking for.

Comment: But instead of using lambdas you could simply write functions for this task: `def create_in(): return PIPELINE_A(arg1, arg2, kw1=kwarg1, kw2=kwarg2)` and then use it in the dictionary: `MODEL_1 = { 'in': create_in, … }`.  You can use local functions for this in case you need to reference local variables (ensure to pass them in this case).  Giving speaking names often clears up the intention of the code.